# how to find source collections.deque?

Tags: python

I need to add functionality to a class that inherits to deque, but prefer to see the code in collections.deque to implement a new class final.

```
>>> from _collections import deque, defaultdict
>>> inspect.getfile(deque)
'/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc'
>>> inspect.getfile(collections)
'/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc'
>>> inspect.getfile(_collections)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 403, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '_collections' (built-in)> is a built-in module
>>>
```

Where can I find the source code of collections.deque?
this is source collections, but does not include collections.deque. -> http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py

Comment: `collections.deque` is implemented in C, not Python.  You'll need to download the python source code and look for `_collectionsmodule.c` for the source code.

Comment: OK, thank for you answer! this is the file.. http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release26-maint/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_collections` is a builtin module.

In CPython this module is written in C:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c

But there is a pure-python implementation in PyPy:
https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/lib_pypy/_collections.py

Comment: Now it is what I expected, now at last I will be able to implement what I need for my program, thank you for the location of the repository.

Comment: Link to PyPy implementation is dead

Comment: yep, they moved to bitbucket

Comment: Updated link to bitbucket is dead as well.